# Laravel Illuminate\Validation\Rule not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

I am trying to submit a form and validate the content.
In one of the requests I need to make a special rule.
I followed the documentation and it says to use unique and declare a Rule.

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
],
]);
```

I am trying with the example from the documentation, but all I get it this error:

```
Class 'Illuminate\Validation\Rule' not found
```

I declared the line

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
```

In my controller, but the error is still there.

Comment: I have the same issue. It seems Laravel don't include the Rule class. I am looking how to add it.

Comment: Did u solve it?

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 6):

The Rule class in the example you posted is for validate an unique field. For examplo if you have an email you will want to be unique in the table, when you are going to edit the record, at saving, will get a validator error because you are saving the same email it is already in the db.

The example you posted:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
],
]);
```

is related to this case, editing a record and validating the email (unique in table users). This example avoid to validate the email against the same user-

For using it you have to add the class (not included in the laravel installator). [Here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Validation/Rule.php) you have it.

In your question you say about using the unique rule. The unique rule is for fields that has to be unique in a table, an email, an personal identification (law), and more. Verify if the unique rule is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

You dont have to use the Rule class for this.

Simply achieve the same with following rule:

```
'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,' . $user->id
```

Comment: i have tried this. But my column name ist not id. I can write .',columnname' but for some reason this is not working. Its not ignoring this entry..

Comment: Whats the column name?

Comment: 'league_id' is the column name

Comment: Then this should work: `'email' => 'required|unique:users,email,' . $user->id . ',league_id'` <-if this doen't work, which laravel version are you running?

Comment: i have tried this before and its not working. I have laravel 5.3

Comment: Well then, your validation rule is correct, but fails due to something else. use `dd()` to try to find what is causing the validator to not work. For example: `$validator = Validator::make(....` `if($validator->fails()) dd($validator->failed)` and so on...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128062/discussion-between-hatemjapo-and-henrik).

Answer (score 0):

The `Illuminate\Validation\Rule` class has been added on Laravel 5.3+.
I almot sure you have tested with an old laravel version.

See issue (PR) 15809: [[5.3] Object based unique and exists rules for validation.](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/15809)

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem on version `v5.3`. I just updated to the latest patch version (`v5.3.31` in my case) and all worked correctly!

Answer (score 0):

```
    use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
],
]);
```

You have done everything ok so far until you add the line
"`Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)`"

The only reason why this is not working is because you are not specifying the column name you want to be unique. Let's assume that, in your database, the column name of the table users that you want to be unique is "email". Then, your code should be as follows:

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;

Validator::make($data, [
'email' => [
    'required',
    Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($user->id),
],
]);
```

Thus,

```
//Right Way
"Rule::unique('users', 'email')->ignore($user->id)"

//Wrong Way
"Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id)"
```

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try in you method something like this:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'email' => 'required|unique:<table_name>',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
    ...
}
```

If you column if also named email laravel will know automaticly, else do

```
required|unique:<table_name>,<column_name>
```

Here is a link to the documentation validation section: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation

Comment: Useless answer. Read the documentation before posting. What he is asking is about the documentation.